# Verify input user password matches hashed password from database on login page c# asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, hash, passwords

I have a login page where the user is directed to input their username and password, which are both stored in the database. The username is stored as plain text but the password is stored as a hashed password with a salt in a MySQL database. I have used the C# code sample from the [crackstation website](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode) and the [youtube video](https://youtu.be/AR7_SHnptZc) by Chris Duran. I am successfully able to register the user and get their password to be hashed and stored in the MySQL database.

I have a simple login page with a textbox for the email address and a textbox for the password that the user must enter. I have an on-click event for my Login button. My code for my login page code behind is as follows:

```
protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    char activation;

    if(Request.QueryString["tokenNum"] != null)
    {
        using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(srlsConnStr))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            {

                OdbcCommand dbCommand = new OdbcCommand();
                dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
                dbCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT tokenNum FROM srlsLogin WHERE user_email_pk = ? and user_password = ?;";

                dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_email_pk", txtUsername.Text);
                dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_password", txtPassword.Text);
                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OdbcDataReader dataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    if ( token == dataReader["tokenNum"].ToString())
                    {
                        updateActivationStatus(txtUsername.Text);
                        userRedirect(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        test.Text = "You are not authorized to login! Please activate your account following the activation link sent to your email " + txtUsername.Text + " !";
                    }
                }
                dataReader.Close();
            }
                dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}

protected void updateActivationStatus(string email)
{
    using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(srlsConnStr))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        {
            OdbcCommand dbCommand = new OdbcCommand();
            dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
            dbCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE srlsLogin set activation_status = 'Y' WHERE user_email_pk = ?;";

            dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_email_pk", txtUsername.Text);
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        dbConnection.Close();
    }
}

//Redirecting the user to correct page
protected void userRedirect(string username, string passcode)
{
    Session["username"] = txtUsername.Text;
    Session["password"] = txtPassword.Text;
    //Session["password"] = PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(txtPassword.Text, "@slowhashsalt");

    using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(srlsConnStr))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        {
            OdbcCommand dbCommand1 = new OdbcCommand();
            dbCommand1.Connection = dbConnection;
            dbCommand1.CommandText = @"SELECT user_status FROM srlsLogin WHERE user_email_pk = ? and user_password = ?;";

            dbCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_email_pk", txtUsername.Text);
            dbCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_password", txtPassword.Text);
            dbCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            OdbcDataReader dataReader1 = dbCommand1.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader1.Read())
            {
                user_status = dataReader1["user_status"].ToString();
                Session["userType"] = user_status;                        
            }

            if (user_status == "Participant")
            {
                Response.Redirect("/srls/StudentUser");
            }
            else if (user_status == "Coordinator")
            {
                Response.Redirect("/srls/CoordinatorUser");

            }                     
            dataReader1.Close();
        }
        dbConnection.Close();               
    }           
}

private void LoginWithPasswordHashFunction()
{
    List<string> salthashList = null;
    List<string> usernameList = null;

    try
    {
        using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(srlsConnStr))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            {
                OdbcCommand dbCommand = new OdbcCommand();
                dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
                dbCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT user_email_pk, slowsalthash FROM srlslogin WHERE user_email_pk = ?;";

                dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_email_pk", txtUsername.Text);
                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OdbcDataReader dataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (dataReader.HasRows && dataReader.Read())
                {
                    if (salthashList == null)
                    {
                        salthashList = new List<string>();
                        usernameList = new List<string>();
                    }

                    string saltHashes = dataReader.GetString(dataReader.GetOrdinal("@slowhashsalt"));
                    salthashList.Add(saltHashes);

                    string userName = dataReader.GetString(dataReader.GetOrdinal("@user_email_pk"));
                    usernameList.Add(userName);
                }
                dataReader.Close();

                if (salthashList != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < salthashList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        bool validUser = PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(txtPassword.Text, salthashList[i]);

                        if (validUser == true)
                        {
                            Session["username"] = usernameList[i];
                            Response.BufferOutput = true;
                            Response.Redirect("/srls/", false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblMessage.Text = "User not authorized! Please try again!";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }            
}
```

I'm a bit new to C# and asp.net and am confused as to how I can use the Session["password"], I know that if I have the plain text version of the password stored to the database table it works fine but I would like to use Session["password"] to be checked against the hashed password so that when the user puts the text password it can be checked against the hashed password in the table and let the user into their account.

Comment: That SELECT statement is not going to hash the plain text password for you, it will simply try to compare two strings, so it will fail. You'll have to hash the password yourself (using the same salt) and then compare the hashed result you got with the one stored in the database

Comment: Please check [MCVE] for guidance on amount/type  of code you should add to the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I took a look at the link about the code and edited it down a bit. The few times I post questions on here, I'm never sure if I have too much or not enough code on here, so I end up posting as much code as I can to show what i'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is old code, maybe there are updates or deprication?? you basically grab the values as you already have in place, and see if it matches, all my Using does it grab the two strings, so you can update that part to your DB call

```
public bool VerifyPassword(string suppliedUserName, string suppliedPassword)
{
    try
    {
        string dbPasswordHash = string.Empty;
        string salt = string.Empty;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = DB.drProc("LookupUser", new SqlParameter[] {
            DB.Parameter("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255, suppliedUserName) }))
        {
            reader.Read();
            dbPasswordHash = reader.GetString(0);
            salt = reader.GetString(1);
        }

        string passwordAndSalt = string.Concat(suppliedPassword, salt);
        string hashedPasswordAndSalt = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(passwordAndSalt, "SHA1");
        return hashedPasswordAndSalt.Equals(dbPasswordHash);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to store the users password in a session. This is what you can do. 
Once the user enters the user name and password and click on the login button of your login page, you can hash the password and pass it to the stored procedure.
You check this hashed password with the password in the database and if everything is fine, you send a return variable back to the code saying that the user is authenticated. You then store this in the session.

Comment: Ok. I was trying to not use a stored procedure but i'll give it a try.

Comment: Ok. I'll see how it goes, being new to C# and asp.net i've never written a stored procedure.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i'm not sure myself. I thought there would be a way to do what I want without having to use a stored procedure. I have tried a few things but I can't seem to get anything to work when it comes to verifying the password the user enters on the login page and the hashed password in the database.

Comment: Skip the stored procedure, just hash the password, and use the sql statement to compare it against the hashed version stored in the database, then if it matches, store a boolean in Session saying the user is logged in, or some object that says he is logged in and stores their application privileges

Comment: @AgapwIesu ok, i'll try that. Thanks for the help. Do I need to rehash the password here on my login page for it to be compared to what the user enters? Because I already hash the password and store the hashed password into my database.

Comment: Yes, you need to rehash it here, and use the rehashed version in your select statement.  Where you put the password into the @user_password parameter, rather than just putting txtPassword.text, put MyHashFunction(txtPassword.text), assuming you have a function that given the password returns back the hashed version.

Comment: can be done with your existing code as well. did not mean to recommend stored procedure as the only possible alternative.. it would make your code look  a lot better ..

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
            dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_password", txtPassword.Text);
```

To

```
            dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_password", PasswordHasher(txtPassword.Text));
```

Assuming you have a function called PasswordHasher that takes a string and returns a hashed version of it.  In fact, anywhere in your code that you do anything with a password, you should not use the password, you should immediately turn it into the hashed version.

Comment: Ok. I have a function called LoginWithPasswordHashFunction and a PasswordHash class (from the crackstation website), that has a ValidatePassword function which takes in a string of the text password and string for hashed password. Could I use that in my code somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my code working. Thanks to everyone who helped me out to solve my problem. I am posting my solution below in case someone has a similar problem in the future and can use this as a reference.

```
protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    char activation;

    if (Request.QueryString["tokenNum"] != null)
    {
        using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(srlsConnStr))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            {
                OdbcCommand dbCommand = new OdbcCommand();
                dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
                dbCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT tokenNum FROM login WHERE useremail = ?";
                dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail", txtUsername.Text);
                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OdbcDataReader dataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    if (token == dataReader["tokenNum"].ToString())
                    {
                        updateActivationStatus(txtUsername.Text);
                        LoginWithPasswordHashFunction();
                    }
                    else
                    {                               
                        test.Text = "You are not authorized to login! Please activate your account following the activation link sent to your email " + txtUsername.Text + " !";
                    }
                }
            }
            dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    else if (Request.QueryString["tokenNum"] == null)
    {
        using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(srlsConnStr))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            {
                OdbcCommand dbCommand1 = new OdbcCommand();
                dbCommand1.Connection = dbConnection;
                dbCommand1.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM login WHERE useremail = ?;";

                dbCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail", txtUsername.Text);
                dbCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OdbcDataReader dataReader1 = dbCommand1.ExecuteReader();
                if (dataReader1.Read())
                {
                    activation = Convert.ToChar(dataReader1["activation_status"]);

                    if (activation == 'Y')
                    {                                
                        LoginWithPasswordHashFunction();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = "Please activate your account following the Activation link emailed to you at <i>" + txtUsername.Text + "</i> to Continue!";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Username or Password";
                }

                dataReader1.Close();
            }
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}

private void LoginWithPasswordHashFunction()
{
    List<string> salthashList = null;
    List<string> usernameList = null;

    try
    {
        using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(srlsConnStr))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            {
                OdbcCommand dbCommand = new OdbcCommand();
                dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
                dbCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT slowhashsalt, useremail FROM login WHERE useremail = ?;";

                dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"useremail", txtUsername.Text);
                OdbcDataReader dataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dataReader.HasRows && dataReader.Read())
                {

                    if (salthashList == null)
                    {
                        salthashList = new List<string>();
                        usernameList = new List<string>();
                    }
                    string saltHashes = dataReader.GetString(dataReader.GetOrdinal("slowhashsalt"));
                    salthashList.Add(saltHashes);

                    string userInfo = dataReader.GetString(dataReader.GetOrdinal("useremail"));

                    usernameList.Add(userInfo);
                }

                dataReader.Close();

                if (salthashList != null)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < salthashList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        bool validUser = PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(txtPassword.Text, salthashList[i]);
                        if (validUser == true)
                        {                                    
                            Session["useremail"] = usernameList[i];

                            OdbcCommand dbCommand1 = new OdbcCommand();
                            dbCommand1.Connection = dbConnection;
                            dbCommand1.CommandText = @"SELECT userstatus FROM login WHERE useremail = ?;";

                            dbCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail", txtUsername.Text);
                            dbCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            OdbcDataReader dataReader1 = dbCommand1.ExecuteReader();
                            while (dataReader1.Read())
                            {
                                user_status = dataReader1["userstatus"].ToString();
                                Session["userType"] = user_status;
                            }

                            Response.BufferOutput = true;

                            if (user_status == "Participant")
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("/StudentUser", false);
                            }
                            else if (user_status == "Coordinator")
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("/CoordinatorUser", false);
                            }
                            else if (user_status == "Instructor")
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("/InstructorUser", false);
                            }
                            else if (user_status == "Coordinator/Instructor")
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("/CoordinatorInstructorUser", false);
                            }

                            dataReader1.Close();

                            Response.Redirect(/StudentUser) - Goes to Login Page";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Username or Password! Please Try Again!";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

protected void updateActivationStatus(string email)
{
    using (OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(srlsConnStr))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        {
            OdbcCommand dbCommand = new OdbcCommand();
            dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
            dbCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE login set activation_status = 'Y' WHERE useremail = ?;";

            dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail", txtUsername.Text);
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        dbConnection.Close();
    }
}
```